# Can I import .dump file to heroku through travis

Tags: heroku, github, travis-ci, heroku-postgres, heroku-api

I am having a QA instance which contains a very limited data(approx 30-35 MB) it contains images etc, thumbnails hence cannot put them into seed.
I have a private repo at github(synced with heroku) which contains a .dump file say `abc.dump` file and I want to run my test cases from travis, in the before script I will be restoring this dump.

I would like to know how to import this dump to heroku although this is available at heroku bash as well. I looked into the [documentation here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import) they say make it asseccible through http somewhere. I am trying using the `pg_restore` commands using the database username, passwords available at the application database overview available through UI, but not working.
Can someone suggest me a good way out to simply restore by not making my database public ?
Also. how often the database user/password is changed at heroku ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As travis would be having access to `abc.dump` beforehand it can perform basic `pg_restore` function of postgresql.

`PGPASSWORD=<PASSWORD> pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h <PG_HOSTNAME> -U <PG_USER> -d <PG_DATABASE_NAME> -p <PG_PORT_NO> <DUMP_FILE>.dump`

The above details for the heroku database hostname, user, pass, port etc. can be fount easily using :-

`heroku pg:credentials DATABASE --app application_name`